# javascript firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword not be able to get success event

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working with `java-script` `fire-base` in my app.

I am able to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` successfully in app. Also it is showing that data inside `Fire-base Console`.

Here is snippet.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("abc@gmail.com", "*******").catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log("Eroor Msg"  + errorMessage);

      // ...
    });
```

Then I have gone through `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

With above method I am not be able to get any success event or message to `log`. Even it is not throwing any `error`.

Here is snippet.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("abc@gmail.com", "*****")
        .catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        alert('Wrong password.');
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
    });
```

My question is how to get success event in this method `signInWithEmailAndPassword` ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 42):

Just check the below code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("abc@gmail.com", "******")
   .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       // Success 
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
       // Error Handling
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a question that how can i manage offline login using this method with firebase ? I mean if user have no internet connection then how can i use this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: Thanks. This is not outlined on the official docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: Bad Official Document.

Comment: This seems to be the correct implementation for signing in.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This must be done using onAuthState object, Below is the code to check if the user logged-in succesfully or not

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

you can run this code after you successfully signed in, BTW there is no object return by SignInWithEmailAndPassword to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Can I be a little critical of other code I see to make people understand when to use "function" with a return event...

```
//run one function only
.then(function(firebaseUser) => this.myfunction(firebaseUser); );

//run lines of code
.then((firebaseUser) => {

        // line1
        // line2

);
```

My code for Ionic, might be a bit different for AngularCLI

```
public async dologinUser(newEmail: string, newPassword: string): Promise<any> {
        try {
          return await this._afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(newEmail, newPassword)

            .then((firebaseUser) => {
              if (firebaseUser) {
                //do something
              }
            })

            .catch((error) => {

              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;

              alert(errorMessage);


            });


        } catch (e) {
          console.error("big hu?", e);
        }

      }
```